# Have to tableView reload data twice to update constraint

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionview, constraints

I have `UITableViewCell` with `UICollectionView` inside. All constraints are setted up. I have a `dataSource` property in my cell. Setter on my dataSource

```
- (void)setDataSource:(id<MyCellDataSource>)dataSource
{
    self->_dataSource = dataSource;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self updateTagsWrapperConstraint];
}

- (void)updateTagsWrapperConstraint
{
    CGFloat height = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;
        self.tagsWrapperHeightConstraint.constant = height;
}
```

Where `self.tagsWrapperHeightConstraint` is my wrapper `UIView` height constraint. The problem is that I have to use double tableView data reloading inside my API fetching method.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

If I don't implement this - my cell will update her height after another data fetching.

P.S I have a second controller where this works up correctly. Help me out. Thanks in advance, Artem. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Still need an aswer